# Flutter Web error - The following UnimplementedError was thrown during a scheduler callback

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I recently tried to build a web version of my flutter app. It is my first time doing so. After many challenges and errors, all solved with various stack posts, this is the current error I am facing:

```
Error: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SCHEDULER LIBRARY ╞══════════════════════
The following UnimplementedError was thrown during a scheduler
callback:
UnimplementedError

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 216:49  throw_
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/html/scene_builder.dart 231:5              pushShaderMask
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1812:26                                                                          addToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 440:5                                                                            [_addToSceneWithRetainedRendering]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1027:14                                                                          addChildrenToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1013:5                                                                           addToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 440:5                                                                            [_addToSceneWithRetainedRendering]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1027:14                                                                          addChildrenToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1164:5                                                                           addToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 440:5                                                                            [_addToSceneWithRetainedRendering]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1027:14                                                                          addChildrenToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1164:5                                                                           addToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 440:5                                                                            [_addToSceneWithRetainedRendering]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1027:14                                                                          addChildrenToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1999:5                                                                           addToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 440:5                                                                            [_addToSceneWithRetainedRendering]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1027:14                                                                          addChildrenToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1164:5                                                                           addToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 440:5                                                                            [_addToSceneWithRetainedRendering]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1027:14                                                                          addChildrenToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1164:5                                                                           addToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 440:5                                                                            [_addToSceneWithRetainedRendering]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1027:14                                                                          addChildrenToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1609:5                                                                           addToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 765:5                                                                            buildScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/view.dart 231:30                                                                            compositeFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 458:18                                                                         drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 895:13                                                                           drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 320:5                                                                          [_handlePersistentFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1117:15                                                                        [_invokeFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1055:9                                                                         handleDrawFrame
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 864:7                                                                          <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1182:47                                          _rootRun
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1093:19                                          run
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 997:7                                            runGuarded
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1037:23                                          <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1190:13                                          _rootRun
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1093:19                                          run
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1021:23                                          <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/isolate_helper.dart 48:19       internalCallback
═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:4348:11)
    at http://localhost:11342/packages/Okuna/pages/auth/create_account/name_step.dart.lib.js:318203:21
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37976:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38007:7)
    at http://localhost:11342/packages/Okuna/pages/auth/create_account/name_step.dart.lib.js:318201:66
    at Function.reportError (http://localhost:11342/packages/flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart.lib.js:3696:56)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_invokeFrameCallback] (http://localhost:11342/packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart.lib.js:771:35)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.handleDrawFrame (http://localhost:11342/packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart.lib.js:734:37)
    at http://localhost:11342/packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart.lib.js:648:14
    at _rootRun (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38250:45)
    at async._CustomZone.new.run (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37426:14)
    at async._CustomZone.new.runGuarded (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37326:14)
    at http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37380:33
    at _rootRun (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38256:14)
    at async._CustomZone.new.run (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37426:14)
    at http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37365:33
    at internalCallback (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:24100:11)
Error: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SERVICES LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════
The following MissingPluginException was thrown while activating
platform stream on channel uni_links/events:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen
on channel uni_links/events)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 216:49  throw_
packages/flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 157:7                                                                  _invokeMethod
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1198:47                                          _rootRunUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1100:19                                          runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 143:18                                    handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 696:44                                    handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 725:32                                    _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 529:5                                     [_completeWithValue]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 567:7                                     <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1190:13                                          _rootRun
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1093:19                                          run
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1021:23                                          callback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 41:11                              _microtaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 50:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15           <fn>
═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:4348:11)
    at http://localhost:11342/packages/Okuna/pages/auth/create_account/name_step.dart.lib.js:318203:21
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37976:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38007:7)
    at http://localhost:11342/packages/Okuna/pages/auth/create_account/name_step.dart.lib.js:318201:66
    at Function.reportError (http://localhost:11342/packages/flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart.lib.js:3696:56)
    at EventChannel.<anonymous> (http://localhost:11342/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:1153:39)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37962:38
    at _rootRunBinary (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38278:45)
    at async._CustomZone.new.runBinary (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37440:14)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleError (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:32783:48)
    at handleError (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:33335:51)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:33361:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:33199:23)
    at http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:33222:35
    at _rootRun (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38256:14)
    at async._CustomZone.new.run (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37426:14)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37365:33)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38071:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38077:13)
    at http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:33574:9
Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:4348:11)
    at Function._operatingSystem (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:54995:17)
    at Function.get operatingSystem [as operatingSystem] (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:55041:27)
    at get _operatingSystem (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:54954:27)
    at Function.desc.get [as _operatingSystem] (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:4842:17)
    at get isIOS (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:54978:26)
    at Function.desc.get [as isIOS] (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:4842:17)
    at flutter_secure_storage.FlutterSecureStorage.new.[_selectOptions] (http://localhost:11342/packages/flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart.lib.js:133:36)
    at flutter_secure_storage.FlutterSecureStorage.new.delete (http://localhost:11342/packages/flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart.lib.js:116:187)
    at storage._SecureStore.new.remove (http://localhost:11342/packages/Okuna/services/storage.dart.lib.js:161:33)
    at storage.OBStorage.new.remove (http://localhost:11342/packages/Okuna/services/storage.dart.lib.js:86:25)
    at user$0.UserService.new._removeStoredUserData (http://localhost:11342/packages/Okuna/pages/auth/create_account/name_step.dart.lib.js:311436:28)
    at _removeStoredUserData.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37976:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38007:7)
    at user$0.UserService.new.[_removeStoredUserData] (http://localhost:11342/packages/Okuna/pages/auth/create_account/name_step.dart.lib.js:311435:20)
    at user$0.UserService.new.logout (http://localhost:11342/packages/Okuna/pages/auth/create_account/name_step.dart.lib.js:309104:44)
    at logout.throw (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37962:38
    at _rootRunBinary (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38278:45)
    at async._CustomZone.new.runBinary (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37440:14)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleError (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:32783:48)
    at handleError (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:33335:51)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:33361:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:33199:23)
    at http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:33222:35
    at _rootRun (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38256:14)
    at async._CustomZone.new.run (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37426:14)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37365:33)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38071:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38077:13)
    at http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:33574:9
Error: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SCHEDULER LIBRARY ╞══════════════════════
The following UnimplementedError was thrown during a scheduler
callback:
UnimplementedError

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 216:49  throw_
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/html/scene_builder.dart 231:5              pushShaderMask
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1812:26                                                                          addToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 440:5                                                                            [_addToSceneWithRetainedRendering]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1027:14                                                                          addChildrenToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1013:5                                                                           addToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 440:5                                                                            [_addToSceneWithRetainedRendering]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1027:14                                                                          addChildrenToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1164:5                                                                           addToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 440:5                                                                            [_addToSceneWithRetainedRendering]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1027:14                                                                          addChildrenToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1164:5                                                                           addToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 440:5                                                                            [_addToSceneWithRetainedRendering]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1027:14                                                                          addChildrenToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1999:5                                                                           addToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 440:5                                                                            [_addToSceneWithRetainedRendering]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1027:14                                                                          addChildrenToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1164:5                                                                           addToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 440:5                                                                            [_addToSceneWithRetainedRendering]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1027:14                                                                          addChildrenToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1164:5                                                                           addToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 440:5                                                                            [_addToSceneWithRetainedRendering]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1027:14                                                                          addChildrenToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1609:5                                                                           addToScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 765:5                                                                            buildScene
packages/flutter/src/rendering/view.dart 231:30                                                                            compositeFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 458:18                                                                         drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 895:13                                                                           drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 320:5                                                                          [_handlePersistentFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1117:15                                                                        [_invokeFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1055:9                                                                         handleDrawFrame
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 971:5                                                                          [_handleDrawFrame]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 892:13            invoke
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 145:5             invokeOnDrawFrame
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine.dart 240:45                                <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1206:13                                          _rootRunUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1100:19                                          runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1005:7                                           runUnaryGuarded
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1042:26                                          <fn>
═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:4348:11)
    at http://localhost:11342/packages/Okuna/pages/auth/create_account/name_step.dart.lib.js:318203:21
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37976:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38007:7)
    at http://localhost:11342/packages/Okuna/pages/auth/create_account/name_step.dart.lib.js:318201:66
    at Function.reportError (http://localhost:11342/packages/flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart.lib.js:3696:56)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_invokeFrameCallback] (http://localhost:11342/packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart.lib.js:771:35)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.handleDrawFrame (http://localhost:11342/packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart.lib.js:734:37)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_handleDrawFrame] (http://localhost:11342/packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart.lib.js:689:12)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:178014:7)
    at _engine.EnginePlatformDispatcher.__.invokeOnDrawFrame (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:160786:15)
    at http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:175633:55
    at _rootRunUnary (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38270:14)
    at async._CustomZone.new.runUnary (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37433:14)
    at async._CustomZone.new.runUnaryGuarded (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37339:14)
    at http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37385:34
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method findProxy on channel social.okuna/proxy_settings)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:4348:11)
    at MethodChannel._invokeMethod (http://localhost:11342/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:943:21)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37956:33
    at _rootRunUnary (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38264:45)
    at async._CustomZone.new.runUnary (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37433:14)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:32771:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:33319:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:33357:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:33199:23)
    at http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:33222:35
    at _rootRun (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38256:14)
    at async._CustomZone.new.run (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37426:14)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:37365:33)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38071:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:38077:13)
    at http://localhost:11342/dart_sdk.js:33574:9
```

I have no idea if these are related errors or 4-5 different errors. I can't seem to find the source of where the error is occuring, in which file in my project. Is there a good way to track the error ?

I seem to have taken all the steps for setting up flutter web. Tried both beta and dev channel.

Comment: Are you sure you do not use packages which are web incompatible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ShaderMask is, at the time of writing, not supported on web.

You will have to figure out what Widget is causing this issue, and work around it or use an alternative until this is implemented.

You can follow [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44152) GitHub issue.